# click function for li is not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my `HTML` I have `ol` and `li` this is my `HTML`
and I have script for those links, like when I click on it i kept a alert to check it its not working

```js
$('#namesId ol li').click(function() {
  alert('clicked');
  //ToDo
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4" id="namesId" style="padding:0px">
  <ol style="padding-left: 10px;">
    <li class="v"><a href="">Funny 10 second video! - YouTube (360p)</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

click function id not working what is the problem with it.

Comment: Where is `namesId` ID ?

Comment: And where is `namesId` defined ?

Comment: May you include the relevant HTML regarding `#namesId` ?

Comment: 2 possible reasons, 1 your not having an element with the id `namesId` or you have not included jquery correctly

Comment: As per shared code, its working fine

Comment: @Rajesh I think the problem is that the OP has not included jquery

Comment: i included both properly , if do same action for other elements its working

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen My guess is, OP is having `a` tag in `li` and he must have redirection on `a`. So before the event is bubbled, redirection happens

Comment: @bharathvarma Can you add `target=''_blank` in `a` tag and check again?

Comment: No its not working

Comment: are the li generated dynamically?

Comment: yes@Mehravish Temkar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: thank you its working@ Alive to Die

Comment: i did@ Alive to Die

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said `li` are generated dynamically, You have to use jQuery [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

So do like below:-

```js
$('#namesId ol').on('click',"li",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('clicked');
  //ToDo
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4" id="namesId" style="padding:0px">
  <ol style="padding-left: 10px;">
    <li class="v"><a href="">Funny 10 second video! - YouTube (360p)</a></li>
    <li class="v"><a href="">Wildlife</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$('#namesId ol').on('click', 'li', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: No need to traverse all the way from document

Comment: yes. BTW i have already up-voted you because at-least concept is correct

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
$('#namesId ol li:nth-child(1)').click(function() {
        alert('clicked');
      //ToDo
});         //for first li click 

$('#namesId ol li:nth-child(2)').click(function() {
        alert('clicked');
      //ToDo
});         //for second li click
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `:nth-child(1`

Comment: You should always leave an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below Code working fine.

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <ol id="namesId" style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <li class="v"><a href="">Funny 10 second video! - YouTube (360p)</a>
               </li>
              <li class="v"><a href="">Wildlife</a></li>
        </ol>
        <script>
        $('#namesId li').click(function() {
                alert('clicked');
              //ToDo
        });

        </script>
        </body>
  </html>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ol id="namesId" style="padding-left: 10px;">
        <li class="v"><a href="">Funny 10 second video! - YouTube (360p)</a>
       </li>
      <li class="v"><a href="">Wildlife</a></li>
</ol>
<script>
$('#namesId li').click(function() {
        alert('clicked');
      //ToDo
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also please notice `<>` icon in editor. You can put your *HTML/JS/CSS* code and make it running snippet.

Comment: User the above code as it only change the src(jquery file location ) part it will be work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have indicated a name for the selector #namesId, but it's not defined anywhere.

Put it this way and it will work:

```
 <div id="namesId">
   <ol style="padding-left: 10px;">
    <li class="v"><a href="">Funny 10 second video! - YouTube (360p)</a>
   </li>
  <li class="v"><a href="">Wildlife</a></li>
 </ol>
</div>
```